# GCP cloud build trigger getting error The caller does not have permission

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, google-cloud-build, cicd

I was trying to integrate gcp cloud build webhook with my gitlab repository. I was using [this](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/build-hosted-repos-gitlab) as reference. I successfully created the trigger(webhook trigger). Also added the necessary permission to the service-accounts and enabled the API as well.

But when I'm trying to use the command like below to trigger the cloud build getting error `PERMISSION_DENIED`

Used command:

```
 curl -X POST -H "application/json" "https://cloudbuild.googleapis.com/v1/projects/${PROJECT_NAME}/triggers/${TRIGGER_NAME}:webhook?key=${API_KEY}&secret=${SECRET_VALUE}" -d "{}"
```

**NOTE:** I've used real value for `TRIGGER_NAME`, `API_KEY` and `SECRET_VALUE`

Getting error like:

```
{
  "error": {
  "code": 403,
  "message": "The caller does not have permission",
  "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

Settings of cloud build:
below is the screenshot of cloud build settings

[image]

How could I invoke this webhook trigger successfully?

Answer (score 1):

Hi make sure your service account or role has the following permissions:

IAM Permission

```
cloudbuild.builds.create
```

Or Using Predefined Role

```
Cloud Build Editor
```

See here for more info: https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/iam-roles-permissions

Comment: I'm using curl with API_KEY, its permission to call cloudBuildAPI. My service account also have permission of Owner(most probably it's not related, not sure though).

Comment: API Key is a deprecated authentication mode for Google Cloud API. Use Authorisation header with a Bearer access token generated from your service account, something similar to that `curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)"  -X POST -H "application/json" "https://cloudbuild.googleapis.com/v1/projects/${PROJECT_NAME}/triggers/${TRIGGER_NAME}:webhook`

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered the same symptom as you do when following the tutorial doc. I resolved this issue by providing a different secret value (e.g. 123) when creating my trigger instead of my ssh-private-key, stored in the secret manager.

The specified secret key would be used as part of the Webhook URL parameter. Since ssh-private-key is way too complicated to have the correct match, using an simpler key could have the match much easier. (I do think the document could be more clear)

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure billing is enabled. Also, double check the keys.

Second, make sure you assign the Secret Manager Secret Accessor role to your Cloud Build service account, ${PROJECT_NUMBER}@gcp-sa-cloudbuild.iam.gserviceaccount.com.

Third, try making the conditions for the trigger something basic and trigger it to see if the build works.